# How to Display more than two ng-show messages

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to display more than two validation messages using ng-show property
it is displaying two messages at the same while entering the input in the text field

```
<input type="text" name="Contact_Person" class="form-control" ng-model="Facility.Contact_Person" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/">
<span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Contact_Person.$invalid && profileform.Contact_Person.$dirty">Please enter the Contact Person</span>
<span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Contact_Person.$invalid && profileform.Contact_Person.$dirty &&  profileform.Contact_Person.$error.pattern ">Contact Person accepts only characters</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `$error.required` and `$error.pattern` to separate the showing error messages based on the type of valid errors.

Note that either of them fails will lead `$invalid` failing.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <form name="profileform">
    <input type="text" name="Contact_Person" class="form-control" ng-model="Facility.Contact_Person" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/">
    <span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Contact_Person.$error.required && profileform.Contact_Person.$dirty">Please enter the Contact Person</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Contact_Person.$error.pattern && profileform.Contact_Person.$dirty &&  profileform.Contact_Person.$error.pattern ">Contact Person accepts only characters</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. But I don't know why you gave profileform.Contact_Person.$error.pattern two time?

Comment: @M.Nithya oh, sorry. I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

change  your code like this.

```
<span class="error" ng-show="!profileform.Contact_Person.$dirty">Please enter 
the Contact Person</span>

<span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Contact_Person.$invalid  && 
 profileform.Contact_Person.$error.pattern">Contact Person accepts only 
 characters</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ng-message](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessage) directive

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error': profileform.Contact_Person.$touched && profileform.Contact_Person.$invalid }">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Contact_Person" ng-model="Facility.Contact_Person" ng-maxlength="35" ng-required="true" />
    <div ng-if="profileform.Contact_Person.$touched && profileform.Contact_Person.$invalid" ng-messages="profileform.Contact_Person.$error" class="error">
        <span ng-message="required">Please enter Contact Person Name.</span>
        <span ng-message="pattren">Contact Person accepts only characters.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="profileform">
<input type="text" name="Contact_Person" class="form-control" ng-model="Facility.Contact_Person" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/">
<span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Contact_Person.$invalid && profileform.Contact_Person.$error.required">Please enter the Contact Person</span>
<span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Contact_Person.$invalid && profileform.Contact_Person.$error.pattern">Contact Person accepts only characters</span>
  </form>
</div>
```